# Getting "Cannot find symbol" error while trying to use complex formula

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class VoltCap {
    public static final double e = 2.71828;

    public void volt_Cap_accept() {
        // called from acceptselection().
        // Here you accept the various values to calculate the voltage
        // a do/while loop. The main exit character here is 'e'/'E'

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int B;
        int initialR;
        int finalR;
        double C;
        String exit;

        System.out.println("Voltage values across a capacitor");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Please enter Battery voltage (integer) (0 for Quick exit): ");
        B = stdin.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter initial resistance value (integer) from: ");
        initialR = stdin.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter final resistance value (integer) to: ");
        finalR = stdin.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter capacitor value (MUST be between 0.2 and 0.8 inclusive): ");
        C = stdin.nextDouble();

        VoltCap v = new VoltCap();
        v.voltCapCalc(B, initialR, finalR, C);      
    } // volt_Cap_accept closing bracket

    public void voltCapCalc(int b, int iR, int fR, double c) {
        // here you calculate the results, from the values you passed to it from volt_Cap_accept.
        // You will need to use a nested for loop

        DecimalFormat twoDecimal = new DecimalFormat("#,###,#00.00");
        double v;       

        System.out.println("=====================================================================");
        System.out.print("\t");
        for (iR = iR; iR <= fR; iR += 100) {
            System.out.print(iR + "\t");
            for (int t = 0; t <= 500; t += 10) {
                System.out.println(v(t) = b(1 - Math.pow(e, -t)/(iR*c)));
            }
        }
    } // voltCapCalc closing bracket
}
```

**v(t) = B(1 - e^-t/(RC))**

```
v(t) = b(1 - Math.pow(e, -t)/(iR*c)) //My attempt at converting it into code
```

I'm really new to Java and I'm trying to use the above formula for an assignment but I keep getting "cannot find symbol" error messages for **v** and **b**. I'm at a complete loss here, can anyone help?

**ERROR MESSAGES:**

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g VoltCap.java

 VoltCap.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
             System.out.println(v(t) = b(1 - Math.pow(e, -t)/(iR*c)));
                                ^
   symbol:   method v(int)
   location: class VoltCap
 VoltCap.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
             System.out.println(v(t) = b(1 - Math.pow(e, -t)/(iR*c)));
                                       ^
   symbol:   method b(double)
   location: class VoltCap
 2 errors

  ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
  ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: You cannot add parenthesis to the end of variable names like that.

Comment: Arrays are indexed with [] not ().  You need a * between b and the ( otherwise it thinks b is a function.

Answer (score 2):

Read the error output carefully.  The symbol `v(t)` is telling Java that you want to call a method called `v()`, passing in `t` as a parameter.  This method does not exist, and you also are not using the evaluation of this expression, so you can just drop it from your print statement.  You are also calling `b()` which again is telling Java you want to call a method called `b()`.  This method does not exist, and it looks like you really want to *multiply* `b` against the rest of the expression.  Try using this code:

```
System.out.println(b*(1 - Math.pow(e, -t)/(iR*c)));
```

Also, instead of defining the constant `e` in your `VoltCap` class, you can use the `e` constant available in the `java.lang.Math` class:

```
import java.lang.Math;
// ...
System.out.println(b*(1 - Math.pow(Math.E, -t)/(iR*c)));
```

Comment: This worked but a whole other bunch of problems popped up. I guess there's something fundamentally wrong with my code, and really it's too late to keep trying (due tomorrow morning). Thanks for the help everyone, I'll definitely take this as a lesson.

Comment: What are the problems?  These other problems were always there, but your compiler was choking on the ones in your question first, "hiding" them.  Send me your email address.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I said that wrong. It's not that more problems "popped up" per se but that there was still a lot more left of the assignment to do that I just legitimately don't have the knowledge to tackle nor the time to learn to. I just underestimated it and got burned. Again, thank you sincerely for the efforts you're going through to help me but I'm waving the flag tonight. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

because in `voltCapCalc` variable v (object of voltCapCalc) is not visible because they are not static at class level, also their are no methods  named `v(t)` and b(), which gives compilation error in your class .

Answer (score 0):

Below line is wrong

```
System.out.println(v(t) = b(1 - Math.pow(e, -t)/(iR*c)));
```

you can modify it as follows

```
System.out.println(v*(t) + " = " + b*(1 - Math.pow(e, -t)/(iR*c)));
```